# Bootstrap-tagsinput: Can't add objects when itemValue option is not set

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

This question was asked so many times, but none of answers helps me.

In short: I have input with some tags. In some cases I need add dynamically a new one. I do it with inbuilt function:

```
$('#msg-receiver').tagsinput('add', { 'id': 1, 'text': 'Ddddd' });
```

It's not working and I still get exception: `Can't add objects when itemValue option is not set`. After a really deep digging in google I found these solutions:

- remove `data-role="tagsinput"` (done, didn't help me)
- add `itemValue` and `itemText` fields to object inserting to `$(elem).tagsinput()` function (done, didn't help me)
- update to newset version (done, didn't help me)

I've prepared some live playground on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shsnowvk/1/).

Does anyone know what else can I do for enable *dynamically added item* feature?

PS. Exception appears in console when you click on button.

Answer (score 3):

**This is not a complete solution** especially if getting value different from the text is needed.
If you dont need the `itemValue` try adding a new item like this:

```
$('#msg-receiver').tagsinput('add','Ddddd');
```

Comment: Uhm, it's workaround, not solution, but I guess there is no another option at the time. Thanks sir for your time.